# Dynamic programming to find two subsets

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, computer-science

> Let `X,Y` subsets of `{1,...,100n}` where `|X|=3n` and `|Y|=7n`. Find `A` subset of `X` and `B` subset of `Y` such that: both are not empty, `|A|=|B|` and `sum a_i = sum b_i`.

- There are `O(n^2)` sums we can make of the set `\{1,...,100n\}` (the largest one is `1+... +100n` even though this one isn't possible since `X` and `Y` don't include all numbers)
- There are `O(n)` cardinals (set sizes) for every sum (from the previous bullet)
- We can have a table of `\{0,1\}` (booleans) with the size of `O(n) X  O(n^2)` where rows represents cardinality and columns represents a number. So `1` means we can create a subset with cardinality `i` and the sum of the set is `j`
- First row/column is easy to calculate of course

Now basically I need to iterate all cells and update them in `O(n)` per cell. So we shall end-up with an overall time-complexity of `O(n^4)`.

How can I do that?

I think I could iterate it row by row; Meaning, if I want to update the cell `T[i,j]` (Meaning, a set with a size `i` of sum `j`), then I could look for a set of size `i-1` plus some term which equals together `j`.

BUT! It could be that **we already used this term in the previous set** (of size `i-1`) - Problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. Your **dynamic programming** should contain another parameter:

Lets define `DP[K,J,I]` to be the number of subsets with size `K` of the first `I` elements that sums to `J`.  The idea of this dynamic programming is that for each element `i` in the set, we check both cases - with adding it to our subset and without adding it.

```
DP[0,0,i] = 1
DP[k,j,0] = 0
DP[k,j,i] = DP[k-1,j-S[i],i-1] or DP[k,j,i-1]
```